# How to see how long a device has been on (For devices that support this)

Tags: 11.10

What tools does Ubuntu have that can say how long a device has been on. The time on should not be based on when Ubuntu was installed since for example the PC could be 2 years old and after that long somebody could have installed Ubuntu. This 2 years could not be taken into consideration. Not to confuse with uptime for example.

Is there a way to determine the time a device has been on or active and what tools can see this. For example I know hard drives can say this. What other devices could and what tools for this devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, hard drives support this through SMART and you can view that data through Disk Utility:

[image]

But past disks, I'm not sure I've ever seen this on other hardware.

Comment: Dude stop answering questions. You have enough points. You greedy guy you! ^^